# PARTITION BY with DISTINCT

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following data. I want to partition on `ID` and only return unique `OrgIDs` based on `Date` desc.

For `ID` 14, `Encompass` and `Premier` were chosen in the output based on the `Date`. For `ID` 57, `Encompass`, `Example` and `Premier` were chosen because `Example` would fall under the unique `OrgID` category.

```
ID  Num  Dx   Code   Describe   OrgID   Nm1     Name        Type         Date
14  242  438  26994  Fractures  4534    2332    ENCOMPASS   AGENCY       2020-01-01
14  242  438  26994  Fractures  4533    2332    Premier     Hospital     2020-02-01
14  242  438  26994  Fractures  4533    2332    Premier     Hospital     2019-08-08
14  242  438  26994  Fractures  4534    2332    ENCOMPASS   AGENCY       2019-07-09
14  242  438  26994  Fractures  4534    2332    ENCOMPASS   AGENCY       2019-08-07
57  242  438  22699  Nervous    4533    2332    Premier     Hospital     2018-01-12
57  242  438  22699  Nervous    4534    2332    ENCOMPASS   AGENCY       2020-01-09
57  242  438  22699  Nervous    4533    2332    Premier     Hospital     2020-01-01
57  242  438  22699  Nervous    4535    2332    Example     Nurse        2019-11-11
57  242  438  22699  Nervous    4534    2332    ENCOMPASS   AGENCY       2019-06-30
```

Expected output -

```
ID  Num  Dx   Code   Describe   OrgID   Nm1     Name        Type         Date
14  242  438  26994  Fractures  4534    2332    ENCOMPASS   AGENCY       2020-01-01
14  242  438  26994  Fractures  4533    2332    Premier     Hospital     2020-02-01
57  242  438  22699  Nervous    4533    2332    Premier     Hospital     2020-01-01
57  242  438  22699  Nervous    4534    2332    ENCOMPASS   AGENCY       2020-01-09
57  242  438  22699  Nervous    4535    2332    Example     Nurse        2019-11-11
```

Comment: You have two columns named `Num`?

Comment: @JoshuaSchlichting Nope. Fixed that. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you could use `row_number()` to get the latest for each `id` and `orgid` pair.

```
SELECT x.id,
       x.num,
       ...
       x.date
       FROM (SELECT t.id,
                    t.num,
                    ...
                    t.date,
                    row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY t.id,
                                                    t.orgid
                                       ORDER BY t.date DESC) rn
                    FROM elbat t) x
       WHERE x.rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

In Postgres, I would recommend `DISTINCT ON`:

```
select distinct on (id, orgid) t.*
from t
order by id, orgid, date desc;
```

This is typically faster than the corresponding query using window functions or subqueries.  And is quite speedy with an index on `(id, orgid, date desc)`.